# jquery ajax request forces incorrect encoding

Tags: jquery, ajax, utf-8

If a create an ajax-request to my url, I get the following content-type (special characters problem):

```
application/json
```

But if I directly open the url in the browser, I get (special characters are displayed fine):

```
application/json;charset=utf-8
```

And exactly the last one is send by the server.

My website, calling the ajax-request, has the following meta tag in head:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

The ajax-request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'MY-URL-AS-USED-HERE-AND-IN-THE-BROWSER',
    type: 'GET',
    contentType : 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    dataType : 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function(r) {
        console.log(r);
    }
});
```

*edit:*

The load-function seems to work. But I'd like to use ajax:

```
$('body').append('<div id="test"></div>');
$('#test').load('MY-URL-AS-USED-HERE-AND-IN-THE-BROWSER');
```

load-function's content-type is the same as the browser request's:

```
application/json;charset=utf-8
```

Comment: Are the headers you're listing in your post request or response headers?

Comment: I'd guess you have a server-side problem then. From the jQuery docs: "The W3C XMLHttpRequest specification dictates that the charset is always UTF-8; specifying another charset will not force the browser to change the encoding." It sounds like your server isn't recognizing the incoming request should use UTF-8 charset. You can also view the request headers to ensure that your browser isn't sending something weird with the AJAX request.

Comment: you realize contentType is only for setting the type you are SENDING TO the server, not what the server responds with, right?

Comment: yes. also removed it. no change. 

$.get('MY-URL-AS-USED-HERE-AND-IN-THE-BROWSER', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});

seems to work (application/json;charset=utf-8). but no ajax. request headers are correct.:/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dataType : 'json'
```

raises the utf-8 problem. I removed it from the .ajax and everything workes fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

I already had this problem and my solution was changing my response (server-side). I started sending my data has a UTF-8 buffer:

```
response.end(new Buffer(JSON.stringify(result.rows), 'UTF-8'));
```

I was using nodeJS in the back end. That works for me so far so... I didn't bother looking for the client-side solution.

Hope it helps. If someone knows why this happen, would like to know too.